# set telegram endpoint for python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram

Telegram is blocked in my location and i want to [this](https://github.com/manzoorwanijk/telegram-bot-api-worker) as an intermediary. is there any way to redefine the telegram endpoint for python-telegram-bot library?